# How do you remove one of “your tags”?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

On the Arqade (gaming) StackExchange in the “my tags” section the [ios] tag is one of them. I want to get rid of that tag because lots of questions have that tag and I don't want to see questions with that tag when I view the “my tags” filter when you search for questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Removing Favourite Tags via Home Page

You can add or remove tags to/from your favourite list, directly from the specific sites home page. You will find this on the right side of the screen. Simply select *"edit"*, and click on the little **x** icon on the tags you wish to remove.

[image]

#### Removing Favourite Tags via Profile

To remove a tag from your favourite list, you will need to access your user profile. This can be quickly done by clicking on your reputation bar, to the top right.

[image]

From here, select *"Edit Profile & Settings"*, and select *"Preferences"* from the side bar.

[image]

Scroll down this page, untill you come to tags. You should see *"Favorite Tags"*, which lists all of the tags you subscribe to. Simply click on the little **x** button, next to the tag, to remove it.

[image]

Note that you can also adds tags to the *"Ignored Tags"* list, which lets you ignore these questions, or gray them out; dependant on the option you have selected, directly underneath.

Also note that you have to do so from the exchange of which you wish to edit the tags; in your case, Arqade.

Answer (score 5):

You can also toggle any tag between "favorite", "ignored", and normal by just hovering over the tag and clicking the star icon in the popup...

> [image]

A filled yellow star means "favorite", a cross means "ignored", and a grey star means neither.

Comment: Yup, most simple way indeed.